# When your spirits are not adapted to a particular situation

Tags: word-request, verbs

Please suppose you are not mentally / emotionally prepared to a particular condition / situation. How can you describe such a situation that your spirits do not compromise with the conditions you are in, idiomatically?

I've heard the following sentence, but have no any idea whether it works properly in this sense or not.

- This situation does not "bode well with" my spirits!

The reason I doubt is that, according to my dictionary definitions, if something bodes well it makes you think that something good will happen. While this concept is far away from the meaning in my mind!

I was wondering if you could let me know whether my example works in this sense appropriately.

If not, please let me know how a native speaker would indicate the same message?

- Some more explanations:

The word "spirits" means "morale", or rather your emotional potencials and the maximum tolerance of you! The degree you can bear a specific situation or some problems! Short and to the point, one's "emotional limits"! I am looking for the nearest and at the same time the most natural way, which a native uses to explain the same situation when you want to say: something is not  with your morale.
Let's suppose a gentle person like a poet or a singer or someone like them who is often times very emotional and cannot bear some harsh things like cutting body organs! So types of people barely can act as successful surgens! Because, the act of surgery [is not compatible with their (spirits/morale)!] How would a native speaker describe such a situation?

Comment: I'm struggling, because I'm not sure what you mean. As a native speaker, I don't think I would use "my spirits" in that way at all.

Comment: The expression is “to bode well *for*” and a similar expression with opposite meaning is “to bode ill *for*.” Not *with*. The first means “to be a good omen for” and the latter means “to be a bad omen for.” Maybe you are also thinking of “to sit well *with*,” which means “to be agreeable to.”

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add the information you've explained in comments.

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering if by 'spirits' you mean 'feeling of confidence', 'happy' or 'well prepared', as when we say somebody is 'in good spirits', and that you want to express how a situation might not be good for you (or whoever is using the sentence)?

So, as best as I can guess, you need to say that something like.

> This is not a situation I feel confident handling.
>
> I am concerned that I may not be properly prepared to handle this situation.

You say 'mentally/emotionally prepared'. When talking about mental health and emotions you may want to be deliberately vague about the specifics. Sadly we still live in a world where there is often stigma attached to matters of mental and emotional health. For instance, if dealing with an employer, you probably don't want to be too direct in admitting to being 'mentally unprepared'. Both sentences above therefore deliberately avoid being too specific.

**However**, if you are happy to say *exactly* what you mean, you could just say:

> I don't feel emotionally and mentally prepared to handle this situation, and it may not be good for me. I think it would be better if it was handled by somebody else.